# Solving Fizz-Buzz with Fourth Power

Tags: number-theory

The question is inspired by a simple game called [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz). The idea is to select multiples of 3 or 5 from a closed sequence of positive integers <1, 2, .. 100>.

It turns out that congruence relation $k^4 \equiv 1\ (mod_{15})$ contains whatever that is not the multiple of 3 or 5. What's the intuition behind this - what's so magical about taking the fourth power modulo 15?

Comment: I think I am missing something here or there is an error w the question. If $k$ is a multiple of 3, so will be $k^4$ mod 15. Likewise if $k$ is a multiple of 5 so will be $k^4$ mod 15.

Comment: @Mike Wolfram Link to a table containing (x, x ^ 4 mod 15) for 1 <= x <= 100. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B(x,+x%5E4+mod+15),+%7Bx,+1,+100%7D%5D

Comment: @Mike Oh youre right, I need to reformulate this! My bad :).

Comment: Glad I could help.....

Comment: @Mike You're 100% right. I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is such that:

All of in this group have 1 as their 4th power. So that should explain the chart.

Comment: I can partially see how 15 would arise, but what's so special about fourth power here?

Comment: The order of this group is 8. Note that 8 divided by 4 is 2. So as with all 8-element Abelian groups, either half or all of the elements have 1 as the fourth power, with half having 1 if and only if it were cyclic (and it is not)

Comment: Oh! :) Thanks..